# WampServer 3.0.6 64Bit cannot open php.ini

Tags: php, wampserver

I am having a problem opening php.ini on the above version of wamp, installed on a windows server 2012 platform.

When I go to the WAMP icon->php->php.ini

i get an error message:

"Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not execute run action: The system cannot find the file specified"

this is a vanilla install of wamp, and everything seems to be operating fine other than this... I need to access php.ini to change some smtp settings, but I can't find it, and neither can WAMP , so it seems

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got to wampmanager.conf and look for: editor =" "
the path to you editor must be the right one

in my case : I use Atom

editor =" C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/atom/**app-1.14.4**/atom.exe"

map : **app-1.14.4** was **app-1.08.1** I change it in the right name and now work perfect.

hope that help !

Comment: sorry for delay getting back, I just managed to have a go, and I can find the wampmanager.conf, but I cannot save any changes to it... it keeps going 'save as...'

Comment: I managed to get the file to save, by opening the editor as an administrator... thanks, it all works sweet now ;o)